# Android Eclipse - App crashing on startup, attempting to implement leaderboard

Tags: java, android

Basically I have a game app which I'm attempting to implement a leaderboard into, I'm following this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-play-game-services-leaderboards--cms-20700 and so far I am trying to allow the app to sign into google play but when I run my app it currently crashes on startup, I get this in my logcat:

Here is my code:

```
public class Mainmenu extends BaseGameActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);


        final Button click=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);       // Button to game
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                            
                     public void onClick(View v) 
                       {             
                         Intent launchactivity= new Intent(Mainmenu.this,Game.class);                               
                         startActivity(launchactivity);                          
                         }
                          });      


        String file = "highscore";


        try{
             FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(file);
             int c;
             String temp="";
             while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
             }
             TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             textview.setText("Highscore: " + temp);


          }catch(Exception e){

          }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
        }
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
            signOut();
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

```
11-28 20:43:00.844: D/AndroidRuntime(25539): --------- beginning of crash
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539): Process: com.jreece.flashytiles, PID: 25539
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.e$h.b(Unknown Source)
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.e$h.g(Unknown Source)
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.e$b.gU(Unknown Source)
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.e$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-28 20:43:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(25539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Post logcat output here, not in an image link which may die.

Comment: Done, its a bit messy though hence why i put a imagine link

Comment: Did you get any additional information from the logs like it says?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is what it means by the logs